# Composer installs jQuery components in wrong directory

Tags: cakephp, composer-php

I'm trying to install jQuery components via Composer in CakePHP app, the composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "affiliate",
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "2.5.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*@dev",
        "cakedc/utils": "dev-develop",
        "cakedc/search": "dev-develop",
        "friendsofcake/crud": "3.*",
        "components/jquery": "2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

And it installs some files in `app/Vendor/components/jquery`, but also it creates and installs some files in APP's root - `app/components/jquery`. I would like to have all in Vendor one, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `components/jquery` package uses [component-installer](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer), which can read from your `composer.json` a specified `component-dir` setting which is where you want to put the downloaded components - e.g. in your `web/assets` folder:

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    }
}
```

To read more about this check out the docs [here](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer#installation-directory).

You can then add those downloaded component files in web/assets to your .gitignore so that you're not adding files which are loaded in by the package manager.

If you're not a fan of this approach, then one other option is that you can add your own package repository to your `composer.json` like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "2.1.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jquery/jquery": "2.1.1"
    }
}
```

With this approach, composer will download the JS file to `vendor/jquery/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js` - you can then add a symlink to this from your www root directory.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've chosen first solution, thus `component/jquery` is in fact a dependency of `ivaynberg/select2`, so it's simply easier to change `component-dir` only.

Comment: Wish we could pipe that stuff to /dev/null.  Using assetic, I prefer to pull specific parts from the actual vendor folders. Thanks for this though, now I can at least get it out of the root.