# How to use a vendor file (installed via Composer) in a Cake-PHP-View?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, composer-php

I've got a problem here, which I have a feeling got a simple and clean solution which I haven't found yet...
My Cake-PHP-Application looks like this:

- Projectfolder

  - app
  - vendors
  - composer.json

Cake-PHP and the external file I want to use are installed inside the vendors-folder.
In vendors I have a package for twitter bootstrap, which has a css- and a js-file I want to include inside my view, but it ain't accessable, since those file don't remain inside the webroot-Folder of my Cake-PHP project.
Now my question is - How do I make those both files accessable inside my Cake-PHP project, WITHOUT copying them to the webroot-folder? Using symlinks looks a bit like a dirty hack to me...
There has to be a clean solution, since otherwise using Cake-PHP with Composer would make no sence.
My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "MyProject",
"version": "0.0.0",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.11",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "2.6.3",
    "composer/installers": "*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "components/jquery": "2.1.3"
},
"extra" : {
  "installer-paths":{
      "plugins/{$name}":["type:cakephp-plugin"],
      "app/webroot/bootstrap":["twbs/bootstrap"]
  }
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "vendors"
}
```

Btw: composer ignores the given installpath for bootstrap, since the package has no type...

Comment: What doesn't make much sense IMHO is to use composer for frontend dependencies, you're better off using something like [bower](http://bower.io).

Comment: You might be right on that, but since I have to use Composer I use it and installing 2 packagemanagers seems weird to me...

Comment: Nothing weird about if you aske me, don't forget that composer is naturally a _PHP_ dependency manager, you'll run into problems with non-PHP packages all the time, resulting in having to use custom installers or the like. Anyways, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/25685722/1392379 (https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer) or http://stackoverflow.com/q/19118367/1392379

Comment: I see your approaches and I don't think that you are wrong on default, but there HAS to be a specific solution to this problem, since cake-php naturally supports composer.
If that wouldn't be the case, the whole composer-cake-symbiosys would make no sense, except for just installating cake with composer and that's it.
Every packagemanager I add, I have to install on the server as well which is bad in my case. :)

Comment: There are no solutions other than using custom composer installers (being it for generic packages or shim ones - is there any reason why you can't use this option?), copying/linking files, or making use of additional dependency managers, you may not like it, but that's simply how it is.

Comment: Again, composer is a PHP dependency manager (the defacto standard btw), and that's why it makes sense for a project like CakePHP, which, naturally, has PHP dependencies. Just do a quick google search, you'll see that there are a lot of PHP projects that are using separate frontend dependency managers, simply because composer has not (yet) evolved in this direction. Just wait and you'll probably also stumble over Grunt :P

Answer (score 1):

Using `tws/bootstrap` will require an additional step for the installation of these assets. This is often done by symlinking or copying.

For instance, when adding Bootstrap to Symfony2 you would require

```
 "require" : {
     "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
     "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
   },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            /* sensio commands **/
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            /* sensio commands **/
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
```

One package is the asset itselfs, the other packages provides the integration and "postInstall" handler for the asset.

For **Cake** you would have to find the package doing the installation job for `tws/boostrap` - maybe such a package is around in the Cake community.

But i would suggest using something easier, which works out of the box:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slywalker/boost_cake": "*"
    }
}
```

And then use enable `CakePlugin::load('BoostCake');` and add the helpers you need.

As @ndm pointed out: you could also decide to work with Composer "bridges" to other asset managers (indirect). One of them is https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin

Or you could work with these asset managers, like bower, npm directly.

Comment: ain't there a way in Cake itself?

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json`, make use of the [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) array.

With CakePHP 3.0, at least, this is pre-built as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Cake\\Composer\\Installer\\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump"
},
```

The `post-install-cmd` script calls the `postInstall` function from `/src/Console/Installer.php`.

If you look at that function, you can see it is doing a few things *after installation*, such as setting file permissions.

In here, you can do anything else that you require, such as building a function to copy files from the `/vendor/` folder, to your webroot folder, using standard PHP functions such as [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) or [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) (to move).