# Composer: eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker installed into components

Tags: composer-php, bootstrap-datetimepicker

For my CakePHP application, I'm trying to install `eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker` via composer.

But, unlike all other packages, it and its dependencies are installed into `components` and not into `vendor/components`:

```
$ composer require eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
Using version dev-master for eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.7.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing robloach/component-installer (0.2.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing moment/moment (2.10.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker (dev-master fd8bd86)
    Cloning fd8bd86dd78f789fb742798b7d49aba0a957af62

kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing twig/twig (Assetic provides the integration with the Twig templating engine)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing patchwork/jsqueeze (Assetic provides the integration with the JSqueeze JavaScript compressor)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump
> ComponentInstaller\Installer::postAutoloadDump
Compiling component files
```

---

```
$ ls -l components/
totale 624
drwxr-xr-x 4 mirko mirko   4096 ott 10 15:07 bootstrap-datetimepicker
drwxr-xr-x 2 mirko mirko   4096 ott 10 15:07 jquery
drwxr-xr-x 4 mirko mirko   4096 ott 10 15:07 moment
-rw-r--r-- 1 mirko mirko 537897 ott 10 15:07 require-built.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 mirko mirko    611 ott 10 15:07 require.config.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 mirko mirko      0 ott 10 15:07 require.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 mirko mirko  81714 ott 10 15:07 require.js
```

By the way, I have noticed that both jQuery and Moment are installed again (because they are dependencies of bootstrap-datetimepicker), although I have those installed already (for my reasons).

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar question about it. You can edit your `component-dir`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "*"
     },
     "config": {
          "component-dir": "web/assets"
     }
}
```

More about it [Composer installs jQuery components in wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685722/composer-installs-jquery-components-in-wrong-directory)

Comment: Thanks @Vinicius, Marked as duplicate.